# npm ci failing on linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

**Current behaviour:**

I'm having a local development environment on mac from which I git push to my remote repo. My production server is on linxu and there I pull my repo. Usually this works fine but this time I'm stuck with an error I can't find a workaround for :(
`npm ci` failing on linux because of `fsevents`

**Steps to reproduce:**

$ `npm ci`

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.2.1: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

**What I've tried:**

- Remove the local node_modules & package-lock.json `$ rm package-lock.json` `$ rm -rf node_modules`
- Update the global npm by `$ sudo npm i -g npm`
- Reinstall the local node_modules by `$ npm install`
- Executing `$ npm ci`
- Also tried `$ npm cache --force clean`
- Also tried `$ npm audit fix`

**Problem:**
I can't find out what dependency is causing the issue as everything is working fine on my Mac. But my google cloud linux server seems to have problems with `fsevents` as it's incompatible. And I can't find out how to fix it or what I should remove. So I'm not able to use my server anymore since this error occurred.

**My package.json**

```
{
  "name": "app-ant",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@dnd-kit/core": "^3.0.3",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.8.3",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^2.0.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "antd": "^4.15.1",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bizcharts": "^4.1.9",
    "core-js": "3.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "exif-js": "^2.3.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^8.7.1",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "gantt-schedule-timeline-calendar": "^3.6.6",
    "google-map-react": "^2.1.9",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.6",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "intl-tel-input": "^17.0.12",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "npm": "^6.14.12",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
    "react-full-screen": "^1.0.2",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.3",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^1.2.6",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-shortcuts": "^2.1.0",
    "react-simple-maps": "^2.3.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "react-to-print": "^2.12.4",
    "react-tracking": "^8.1.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.9.0",
    "recharts": "^2.0.9",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "vcards-js": "^2.10.0",
    "vcf": "^2.1.0",
    "xmp-js": "0.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env HOST=website.com react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@iconify-icons/bx": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify-icons/el": "^1.1.0",
    "@iconify-icons/mdi": "^1.1.14",
    "@iconify/react": "^1.1.4"
  }
}
```

**npm_dependencies_tree output:** `npm ls --all`

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-yZ289sT3kOUPtb-KzewwSlGdF22jXZ6/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance for your support on my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well-known problem, one of your package dependencies needs `fs-events` when running on macOS.

When Node.js is running on Linux,this package is not needed, and since you are using `--ci` flag, it fails to install `fs-events` on Linux.

You can try removing `--ci` flag or you can try adding `fs-events` in `optionalDependencies` in your package file.

```
"optionalDependencies": {
  "fsevents": "*"
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would i remove the `--ci` flag as I need it to install my dependencies?

Comment: And do you mean I should insert it into the `package.json` ?

Comment: Thank you for this, this at least helped me for now. I've seen that there are multiple discussions going on why npm isn't fixing that and even a few people switched to yarn.